# React - unit testing HOC’s wrapped component - testing state

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, enzyme, higher-order-components

I want to test state of my ReactJS application using Enzyme.
Simple test - if state will change, modal is showing up - but I get error:
`ShallowWrapper::state() can only be called on class components`
My component is class component.

```
 class Component extends PureComponent<ComponentProps> {

  public state = {
    hasError: false,
  };

  public render() {
    const { hasError } = this.state;
    return (
      <>
        <Modal
          isOpen={hasError}
          type="error"
        />
        <button onClick={this.onBtnClik}
      </>
    );
  }

private onBtnClik = () => this.setState({ hasError: true})

 export default compose(
  withRouter,
  withStyles(styles),
  connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps),
)(Component) as any;
```

As you see I have a lot of HOC's and I cannot test my state. I found this article:
https://medium.com/c-hive/test-hocs-wrapped-component-with-jest-and-enzyme-e9155f80a217
but: `wrapper = shallow(shallow(<MyComponent />).get(0));` still not helping me so I am a little confused and will be very grateful for any advice.

My test:

```
  it('should open Modal when error state is true', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(shallow(<Component />).get(0));
    expect(wrapper.state('hasError')).toBe(true);
  });
```

Comment: It is sometimes suggested to also export your component so that you can test it without all the HOCs. I have to admit I'm not a fan of this method but it should work.

Comment: That's what I want to avoid. Anyway, thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

Bro u have use dive() while testing HOC components
look into [enzyme's dive](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/dive.html)

```js
wrapper.dive()
```